# Декомпиляция программы С++

Tags: c++, компиляция, декомпиляция

Как мне получить код из exe`шника который написан на С++? Если возможно, то как? А если нельзя, то почему?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/273145/7485582

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Дизассемблер IDA PRO - уникальный в своём роде инструмент для исследования, отладки и, при необходимости, модификаци программ, когда нет исходных текстов. Декомпиляторы в псевдокод С++, конечно, имеются (IDA тоже это умеет), но проку от них будет мало. Только ассемблер!

Вот скриншот IDA PRO:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "единственный и незаменимый" - не единственный, и не незаменимый.